# Question about using return value in python

Tags: python

```
def multiples(n, i=1):
    if i != 11:
        multiples(n,i+1)
    return n*i

print(multiples(2))

output:
2
```

Here is a simple example,

I want all the multiples printed (2 to 22) so I can use it in another function.

Could someone explain to me why it prints 2 only?

Comment: Try to explain to me first why you think it should print anything else. If, instead of the recursive call to `multiples`, it called a *different* function, would you expect the result from *that* function to be printed? How and why? If not, then why should it work any differently for a recursive call?

Comment: `return multiples(n,i+1)`

Comment: @KlausD. That would still not print all multiples.

Comment: But that is the first problem to fix. If you have additional advice please add it!

Comment: I don't understand what you want the code to do. Your simple example doesn't show what you expect `i` to do. You are getting the value 2 because:  (1) the `for` loop makes 10 recursive calls to `multiples`; (2) the calling code then throws away the values that those calls return; so (3) the `for` loop has no effect; and (4) the only effective line of code  is `return n*i`; which (5) just returns the value passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it will be implemented with recursion or why recursion is necessary here in your code but if you just want to get the multiples then this will work:

```
def multiples(n, i=1):
        while i != 12:
            print(n*i)
            i += 1

multiples(2)
```

I would suggest you to learn the basics of recursion, function calling etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at what your function do from 1 to 11.

For `multiples(2)`, the parameter of function is n=2, i=1, and find i is not equal to 11, which satisfied the condition, so the function call `multiples(2, 2)`

Next the `multiples(2, 2)`, the value i=2 is still not equal to 11, so the function call `multiples(2, 3)`, and so on until i = 11.

When `multiples(2, 11)` is called. the condition is not satisfied. So the function return 2 * 11 = 22 immediately, and go back to `multiples(2, 10)`

But after `multiples(2, 11)`, the return value is discarded and the function `multiples(2, 10)` return 20

So after all the recursive, the function `multiples(2)` will only return 2 and will not get the return value of `multiples(2, 2)`

If you want to print all the value of recursive. I suggest you can use the method below:

```
def multiples(n, i=1):
    if i >= 11:   # it is suggested to use greater then to prevent decimal numbers error
        return [n*i]+ multiples(n,i+1)   # add current value and next recursive value
    else:
        return [n*i]   # if i is greater then 11, return value and stop recursive  
        
print(multiples(2))
```

output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make any use of the returning value of the recursive call, and therefore it returns only the value returned by `return n*i` at the first level.

Since you're looking to produce a sequence of numbers, it's best to make your function a generator instead by yielding the product of `n` and the current `i` and then yielding the sequence from a recursive call until `i` reaches the desired maximum `m`:

```
def multiples(n, i=1, m=11):
    yield n * i
    if i < m:
        yield from multiples(n, i + 1, m)

for i in multiples(2):
    print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
```